# Python path.exists and path.join

Tags: python, python-2.7, join, path

Python 2.7: 
Struggling a little with path.exists

```
import os
import platform
OS = platform.system()
CPU_ARCH = platform.machine()

if os.path.exists( os.path.join("/dir/to/place/" , CPU_ARCH) ):
    print "WORKED"
    # Linux
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH = "/dir/to/place/" + CPU_ARCH
    TRANSCODER_DIR  = LD_LIBRARY_PATH + "/Resources/"
else:
    print "FAILED"
    #fail back to original director if processor not recognised
    TRANSCODER_DIR  = "/dir/to/place/Resources/"
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH = "/dir/to/place"
```

As soon as I stick os.path.join with a variable inside it the if statement fails.

```
os.path.exists("/dir/to/place/arch")
```

returns TRUE

```
os.path.exists("/dir/to/place/" + CPU_ARCH)
```

returns FALSE

I have tried many variations on the different path commands and to string commands none of them allow me to change this with a variable.

```
os.path.join("/dir/to/place/", CPU_ARCH)
```

returns /dir/to/place/arch

it's not a permissions issues either full perms granted and I've tested using the python cli on it's own still the same issue.

I've looked at all the stack posts for the same issue and the only response I've seen that someone says has worked is to strip the white space, I'm pretty new to python I don't see any whitespace on this.

Comment: os.path.exists("/dir/to/place" + CPU_ARCH) is like os.path.exists("/dir/to/placearch") missing the slash (if CPU_ARCH is "arch"), so I would expect it to be False.

Comment: Have you printed out `CPU_ARCH` to ensure you're getting the value you want? Because if it can't determine the architecture it will return an empty string.

Comment: CPU_ARCH is returning the correct value.

Comment: sorry Andrew that was my lazy typing I will correct that, I'd tried both with more slashes and without slashes everywhere. Hasn't helped at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.path.exists` checks if a path exists.

if `/dir/to/place/arch` exists, then

```
os.path.exists("/dir/to/place/" + CPU_ARCH)
```

should return True. **Notice the trailing / after `place` that is missing in your example**

`os.path.join` will join all its arguments to create a path.

```
# This joins the two arguments into one path
os.path.join("/dir/to/place/", CPU_ARCH)
# >>> '/dir/to/place/x86_64'
```

Explaining your results.

Comment: Neither returned true, I'm using debian on a rpi B+ so my CPU_ARCH is 'armv61'
I want os.path.exists(os.path.join("/dir/to/place/", CPU_ARCH))
All makes sense in my mind, but returns false which gives me a sad face.

Comment: `ls /dir/to/place/armv61` actually returns something ?

Comment: Didn't actually change anything other than rebooted the computer... then started working. I'm so confused. Sorry to waste your time.

Answer (score 0):

If `/dir/to/place/arch` exists I would suggest setting arch to `CPU_ARCH = platform.machine().strip()` as there may be whitespace on the end of the string causing it to fail. And possibly setting it to a variable to be reused by `LD_LIBRARY_PATH = var`.

Comment: I've added .strip() to my two items that's for the input.

Answer (score 0):

This also might help to navigate in path.

```
#current directory
os.path.abspath('.')
#parent directory
os.path.abspath('..')
#parent of parent directory
os.path.abspath('../..')
```